# Pass Data From View Controller to View in MVC - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, pass-data

Passing data between `UIViewControllers` is fairly straightforward, but passing data from a controller to a view is something I can't seem to figure out.

In my specific case the user taps on an "event" cell, and transitions into a detailed view.

How do I pass the "event" from the tapped cell, to the detail view?

```
// Inside Starting View Controller
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = EventDetailController()
    let vcView = vc.view as! EventDetailView
    vcView.event = model.events[indexPath.item]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}



// Second View
class EventDetailView: UIView {

    var event: Event?     
    let model = EventsModel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("selected event: \(event)") <<<<--- Prints "nil"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


// Second Controller
class EventDetailController: UIViewController {

    var eventDetailView: EventDetailView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view = eventDetailView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }  
}
```

Comment: init already happened with this line ` let vc = AddEventController()`. by that time you haven't assigned any event. But if you are using that event later you won't have any issue. It will be ok

Comment: @RJE But is there a way to use that "event" to populate different views in the detail controller?

Comment: maybe something like this `let vc = EventDetailController(addEvent: Event?)`, Then do if else to create the correct view. But if you don't need the event just send some id only. No need event.

Comment: @RJE I don't need the event in my controller though, I need it in my view

Comment: yeah, send it yo ViewController init and set the event to view (or create a view accordingly, if you are creating the view).

Comment: @RJE I'm not sure I understand. I can send the "event" to my controller, but how do I send it to my view before the view begins to draw everything out?

Comment: in `EventDetailView`cutom init `init(frame: CGRect, event; Event?)`, then add it to the view of the View Controller

Comment: Why can't you inherit your "EventDetailView" class from NSObject instead of UIView, by that you can set values in viewDidLoad() or loadView() of EventDetailController from your EventDetailView model class that you are passing from First View Controller.

Comment: @BhavikModi How do I do that? Changing the class inheritance to NSObject takes away all the things such as self.addSubview(). And adding the NSObject inheritance in combination with the UView inheritance throws an error as well.

Comment: @yambo check answer for code

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data which is not the correct way to do this. You should never access the view until it's been shown or loaded correctly.

In your  `class EventDetailController` add the property

```
var event: Event?
```

and  replace this method like below

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = EventDetailController()
    vc.event = model.events[indexPath.item]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

and

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   eventDetailView.event = self.event   
}
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

In load view method  add the following line at the start of the method

```
 `eventDetailView = EventDetailView(frame:CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height))`
```

Comment: I tried that prior to posting my question and it prints "nil"

Comment: @yambo Check the edit. You need to init the eventDetailView. that's why you get nil

Comment: I'm still getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
// First View Controller

let vc = EventDetailController()
vc.eventDetailView.event = "TEST"
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)


// Second View
class EventDetailView: UIView {

    var event: String?
    var model =  EventsModel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("selected event: \(event)")
    }

    override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        super.encode(with: aCoder)
        aCoder.encode(event as Any?, forKey: "event")
        aCoder.encode(model as Any?, forKey: "model")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        event = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "event") as? String? ?? ""
        model = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "model") as! EventsModel? ?? EventsModel()
    }
}

// Second Controller
class EventDetailController: UIViewController {

    var eventDetailView = EventDetailView()

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view = eventDetailView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(eventDetailView.event)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using storyboards, and this just passes the data to the controller, not the view

Comment: @yambo I have tested at my end and its working great. You may missing something over there! or you might expecting something else!